# Extract one NOT NULL value for each column name in my tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, information-schema

This is the query I use to get tables metadata from SQL Server database to include db_name, table_name, column_name, data_type and others

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

How can I join every table in my database to **`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`** to get a `Non NULL` sample `value` from each `column` if any a Non NULL exited. This will help validate if any column has an IP address as a value down the road for **special treatment**. Also if a column has at least one `NOT NULL` value. I'm sure is could be used for other use cases for the community.

Comment: You'll need some form of dynamic SQL to build a list of select statements using the column names obtained.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is the purpose, the most important is to get a sample value for each column in each table in the database that is not NULL is it's null show a value sample as NULL

Comment: @DaleK That's the right way to go about it. Build a `SELECT schema.*, tb1.column_name as sample_value FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS schema LEFT JOIN db_name.schema_name.table_name tb1 ON tb1.table_name= schema.TABLE_NAME AND tb1.db_name = schema.TABLE_CATALOG AND tb1.schema_name = schema.TABLE_SCHEMA AND tb1.column_name = schema.COLUMN_NAME AND tb1.column_name IS NOT NULL` statements for all the columns with `UNION ALL` between them all

Comment: @mongotop so whats stopping you? Have a go, post a question when stuck...

Comment: @DaleK for sure! like anything else, there's always a better way to do things. I was hopping somebody was able to achieve it in a more easily way instead of automating 500 LEFT JOIN statements because that's how how tables I have in my SQL Server instance

Comment: @AaronBertrand its about the speed. imagine selecting one `NOT NULL` value from each column in 500 tables, that is about 10k queries minimum assuming each table has only 20 columns avg and of course not  all those columns have indexes or primary keys. I would say I'm over 15k+ queries with that logic.